# Attaching custom field to Mongoose Schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

So I have **Story** and **Comment** model. 
Also, I have INDEX and SHOW routes.

So on INDEX route, I am interested in returning just number of published comments. I made the next method:

```
StorySchema.methods.comments = function (cb) {
    return this.model('Comment').find({ storyId: this._id, published: true }, cb);
}
```

And this is my INDEX route (currently showing 4 newest stories):

```
Story.find({}, '-content')
        .sort('-dateCreated')
        .limit(4)
        .exec((err, found) => {
            found.map(async f => f.comments = await f.comments())

            if (err) return res.json({ err });

            res.json(found);
        })
```

I do not have ***comments*** field defined in StorySchema, but I wanna attach it just for show reasons, I do not intend to save it. Problem is, ***comments*** field is not showing. Even if I define it in Schema, it does not change.

How do I attach a field to mongoose Document, just for show purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Query you've written above

```
Story.find({}, '-content')
```

is equivalent to

```
Select -content from Story
```

Inshort, when you project a field to be added in response, that is the only field which will be project to you as response.

For your case, you may consider using [**`aggregation`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) framework and its pipeline [**`$project`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) or [**`$addField`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) , That's why they are here. I mean they don't modify your document schema. And yeah they can be easily used to project extra fields in your response. And you can even use multiple operators or expressions to add values to those dummy fields

Comment: Is there another way to handle this? Maybe like a virtual field? And how would you write this in aggregation?

Comment: I've attached links with my answer already. still https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/ 

here you can find the examples

Comment: I' more intrested in mongoose way to handle this, not mongodb?